# Encrypting username/password files (app.config) and Unit Tests on Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: unit-testing, encryption, azure-devops, mstest, aspnet-regiis.exe

I have some unit tests which target some overriden app.config files. Each config file has encrypted password/username using `DataProtectionConfigurationProvider` via **aspnet_regiis.exe**

This is all fine and dandy on my local machine where they are created. Now when these are deployed and run to our **Visual Studio Team Services** and the build definition is run, the tests that target the encrypted credentials methods fail because:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Failed to decrypt
>   using provider 'DataProtectionConfigurationProvider'. Error message
>   from the provider: Key not valid for use in specified state.

I appreciate that this error is caused by not running aspnet_regiis.exe on the local machine the app/tests will be running on.

My question is what is best practice here? Because even if i build a Team Service build definition which runs aspnet_regiis.exe (I presume you can do that) against an unencrypted app.config file first, I'm still storing unencrypted data online for a while.

**EDIT:**

The answer helped me identifier I needed to use `RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider` instead of `DataProtectionConfigurationProvider` I did alittle blog post here explaining what I did:

[Encrypting credentials in app.config files](https://mywebanecdotes.com/2016/09/17/encrypting-credentials-in-app-config-for-multiple-machines/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encryption key for this uses the machine key which will differ up on the azure server to your local box.  Set a machine key manually so it will always be the same in the web.config

See this article on setting your machine key..
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc755177(v=ws.10).aspx